# Gradle task configuration avoidance and findByPath

Tags: gradle, groovy

Suppose you are currently refactoring some Gradle code to take advantage of the task configuration avoidance APIs. According to the documentation, it is said that you should avoid using `TaskContainer.findByPath()`, but does not state an alternative.

So, suppose I have this in my build.gradle:

```
tasks.register('myTask') {
  dependsOn tasks.findByPath(':foo:bar')
}
```

If what I am reading of the documentation, then rewriting the above as

```
tasks.register('myTask') {
  dependsOn project('foo').tasks.named('bar')
}
```

essentially has no effect due to the way that `project('foo')` needs to be resolved first. Is this correct? Is there no way to safely use the task configuration avoidance API in this case?

Comment: Reaching across projects is not recommended, dependencies between projects should be modeled by outputs, not via direct task dependencies.

Comment: While true, we are talking about a refactoring scenario, where this issue may itself also need to be addressed.

Comment: You can use `evaluationDependsOn(":foo")` to make sure that it the other project is evaluated first, so that the task is registered, but I'm not sure that this will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> but does not state an alternative.

Correct because there is no direct equivalent as explained in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:old_vs_new_configuration_api_overview) in addition to:

> Accessing tasks from another project requires a specific ordering of project evaluation.

What you have now does not change the fact that there is still a requirement on the specific ordering of project evaluation. The only difference is that you are now using a task provider instead of the task.

> essentially has no effect due to the way that `project('foo')` needs to be resolved first. Is this correct? Is there no way to safely use the task configuration avoidance API in this case?

Correct and no, there is no safe way (you can use `evaluationDependsOn`, but that still does not solve the underlying problem). As explained in the docs above you are relying on the ordering of project evaluation. The way to fix it is what user16358266 explained in the comments which is documented in [Sharing outputs between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html)
.